# Is This An Acceptable Way To Save Images To A mysql DB?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've gone back and forth on a few ways of saving multiple image (paths) to the database to be stored and used in a carousel.

I will eventually be doing this in Wordpress, but I have just been testing how the data would work properly.

There will be a number of inputs with the name="image[]", and then each image will be concatenated (although separated by spaces). From there I will insert it into the database.

Then after querying to retrieve the string I will match all URL's and do with them what I want.

So far it works great, and I have tested it on multiple URL paths.

I still have to set up validation, but my question is .... **what are the pro's and con's of saving image information to a database like this**?

Here is the code:

```
<form action=<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?> method="post">
  <input type="text" name="images[]"/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="images[]"/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="images[]"/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="images[]"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/><br/>
</form>

<?php
    if($_POST['images']){
        foreach($_POST['images'] as $image)
        {
            if($image){
                $image_data .= $image . " ";
            }
        }
        echo $image_data;
        // actually insert this into the db
    }

    $pattern = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
    $result = preg_match_all($pattern, $image_data, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach($matches as $match){
        foreach($match as $image){
            if(!empty($image)){
            echo '<p>Image: ' . $image . '</p>';
            // Actually display in some sort of manner that is a image carousel
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Don't put multiple information sections in one field, it makes searching and data retrieving a lot harder. If you must do it like that, at the very least serialize the data from an array, don't concatenate with spaces, I can't count the times I've seen spaces in file-names on the web...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think saving web-served images to databases is acceptable at all. Think of the overhead it causes to involve the entire webserver/php/database stack just to get a single image delivered. Bottom line: A database is a poor substitute for a file system.

Comment: I very much second that.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about images but about image paths. The code seems to suggest the same, just texts...

Comment: Oh indeed. Snap. That's what you get when you see "SQL blob is a VFS!"-type code all day ...

Comment: No worries, it's a bad idea just the same :)